# Fisher's Information for Laplace distribution

Tags: self-study, fisher-information, laplace-distribution, indicator-function

Say we have $f(x , \theta) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x-\theta|}$
Lets assume for simplicity, we only have 1 sample.
We find that the log-likelihood for this distribution is: 
$$
l(\theta , x) = -log(2) + (\theta - x) I_{(x < \theta)}+(x-\theta)I_{(x \geq \theta)}.
$$

Now in general, Call the score function: 
$$
S(\theta , X) = Dl = \frac{Dg_{\theta}}{g_{\theta}}
$$
by noticing the log-likelihood is expressed as : 
$$
l(\theta, X) = log (g_{\theta})
$$ 
Where g is the likelihood
and assume $g$ is 3 times differentiable. Furthermore, we find : 
$$
DS = \frac{D^2g_\theta}{g_\theta}- SS'.
$$
Which finally allows us to obtain that : 
$$
var_\theta S = -E_\theta DS
$$ by noticing that $E_\theta S = 0$

Now in this case: 
$$
Dl = \frac{dl}{d\theta} = I_{(x < \theta)} - I_{(x \geq \theta)}
$$

So indeed 
$$
E_\theta S = P{(x < \theta)} - P{(x \geq \theta)} = 0
$$
And then $\frac{dS}{d\theta} = 0$ so $-E_\theta \frac{dS}{d\theta} = 0$

Now computing 
$$
ES^2 = E( [I_{(x < \theta)} - I_{(x \geq \theta)}]^2) = E(I_{(x < \theta)} + I_{(x \geq \theta)}) = 1.
$$
This does not match the case above, however here do not have differentiability. Is what I did correct, or plain fiction?

Comment: Is it necessary to use two different notations for derivatives? Will it be easier to read if only one notation were used? What is $g_\theta$,

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha good point, added it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your notation is ridiculously over-complicated for what you're doing.  For the Laplace distribution with unit scale (which is the density you have given) you have $l_x(\theta) = - \ln 2 - |x - \theta|$, which has the (weak) derivative:

$$\frac{\partial l_x}{\partial \theta}(\theta) = \text{sgn}(x- \theta) \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ for } x \neq \theta.$$

Hence, the Fisher information for the location parameter is:

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta) = \mathbb{E} \Bigg[ \Big( \frac{\partial l_X}{\partial \theta}(\theta) \Big)^2 \Bigg| \theta \Bigg] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ \text{sgn}(X-\theta)^2 \Big| \theta \Big] = \mathbb{E} [ 1 | \theta ] = 1.$$

(The fact that the derivative is undefined at $x = \theta$ does not affect this calculation, since this occurs with probability zero.)

Comment: Indeed, the variance equals 1 (edited above). How come we do not have variance equals 0, which is what the general case would give us!

Comment: What general case are you referring to?

Comment: $var_\theta S = -E_\theta DS$ (proved above)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot understand how you're getting this result (but obviously it's wrong so it cannot have been proved).  The first thing you need to do is make a major clean-up of your notation, to make your argument more intelligible.  I count three different notations for derivatives just for starters.

Comment: I am pretty sure the above in right in case where the likelihood is differentiable, which is not the case here. Perhaps that is what breaks. To me this makes sense now! Thank you, you helped confirm by also getting 1 for the variance.