# Fisher information for double exponential distribution

Tags: fisher-information

I am asked to find the Fisher information function for double exponential distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance 1.

Here's my approach:
$l(\mu) = -\frac{1}{2}e^{|x-\mu|}$,
so $\log l(\mu) = constant  + |x-\mu| $,
$\frac{d\log l(\mu)}{d\mu} = -1$ if $x>\mu$
$\frac{d\log l(\mu)}{d\mu} = 1$ if $x<\mu$

Then $I(\mu) = Var(\frac{d\log l(\mu)}{d\mu}) = 0$

I suspect that this approach is wrong, please advise.

Comment: The expectation of the score is zero, so the FI is the expectation of the score SQUARED, which as you'll note here is 1.

Comment: @SheridanGrant Thanks. I understand your solution. However, I don't get why using variance would get different result?

Comment: It doesn't, you're just calculating variance wrong--I think you're forgetting to square the values.

Comment: @SheridanGrant wouldn't the variance of a constant be 0?

Comment: This is not a constant, it depends on $x$.

Comment: See [Answer to question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333568/fishers-information-for-laplace-distribution) on this page.

Comment: @Bruce Thanks, well spotted. However, when a question seems answered by an answer to a previous question, please vote to close as a duplicate to save people unnecessarily answering a question already well answered. When it closes, the closed question helps direct people looking for an answer who find the closed one to good answers already given (and gives a good place for people with other good answers to put them, so they're all on one page, which then acts as the "canonical question")

Comment: Oh whoops yeah this is definitely a duplicate